# Beautiful Soup AssertionError

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to scrape this website into a .CSV and I am getting an error that says: **`AssertionError: 9 columns passed, passed data had 30 columns`.** My code is below, it is a little messy because I exported from Jupyter Notebook.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://apps.azsos.gov/apps/election/cfs/search/CandidateSearch.aspx'

req = Request(url , headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

type(soup)  # we see that soup is a BeautifulSoup object

column_headers = [th.getText() for th in 
                  soup.findAll('tr', limit=2)[1].findAll('th')]
column_headers # our column headers

data_rows = soup.findAll('th')[2:]  # skip the first 2 header rows

type(data_rows)  # now we have a list of table rows

candidate_data = [[td.getText() for td in data_rows[i].findAll('td')]
            for i in range(len(data_rows))]

df = pd.DataFrame(candidate_data, columns=column_headers)
df.head()  # head() lets us see the 1st 5 rows of our DataFrame by default

df.to_csv(r'C:/Dev/Sheets/Candiate_Search.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Comment: `column_headers` has 9 elements, and your data seems to have 30 columns.

Comment: My column header function is returning 9 columns. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think there is a list contains 30 elements in `candidate_data`.Can you check that?

Comment: Check @mattbornski's answer please.

Answer (score 1):

The data on the page [[image: screenshot of given url 1]] definitely has a table, and you parse out the column headers and pass them to your CSV.  Visually that table has 8 columns, but you parse 9 headers.  At this point you should probably go check your data to see what you've found - it might not be what you expect.  But okay, you go and check and you see that one of them is a spacer column in the table that will be empty or garbage, and you proceed.

These lines:

```
data_rows = soup.findAll('th')[2:]  # skip the first 2 header rows

type(data_rows)  # now we have a list of table rows

candidate_data = [[td.getText() for td in data_rows[i].findAll('td')]
        for i in range(len(data_rows))]
```

find *every* `<th>` instance in the page and then *every* `<td>` inside each `<th>`, and that's where it really goes off the rails.  I am guessing you are not a web developer, but tables and their sub-elements (rows aka `<tr>`, headers aka `<th>`, and cells aka `<td>`) are used all over most pages for organizing tons of visual elements and also sometimes for organizing tabular data.

Guess what?  You found a lot of tables that are not this visual table because you were searching the *whole page* for `<th>` elements.

I'd suggest you pre-filter down from using the entire `soup` by first finding a `<table>` or `<div>` that only contains the tabular data you're interested in, and then search within that scope.

Comment: Would formatting the code in such a way as this make sense?  `table = soup.find( "table", {'class' : 'rgMasterTable rgClipCells'} )

rows=list()
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
   rows.append(row)`

Comment: that would likely work, although with `table = soup.find( "table", {'class' : 'rgMasterTable rgClipCells'} )` you could then just change `data_rows = soup.findAll('th')[2:]` to `data_rows = table.findAll('th')[2:]` I believe and it should be limited to the correct scope