# How to scrape data from last table on website

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the "team per game stats" table from this website using this code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uo
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020.html'
html = uo(url)
soup = BS(html, 'html.parser')
soup.findAll('tr')

headers = [th.getText() for th in soup.findAll('tr')]
headers = headers[1:]
print(headers)

rows = soup.findAll('tr')[1:]
team_stats = [[td.getText() for td in rows[i].findAll('td')]
                for i in range(len(rows))]

stats = pd.DataFrame(team_stats, columns=headers)
```

But it returns this error:

```
AssertionError: 71 columns passed, passed data had 212 columns
```

Comment: There's no assert in your code, can you please post the full stack trace?

Comment: Also, is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59634423/beautiful-soup-assertionerror) the same problem you're having?

Comment: Might want to have a look at [this git](https://github.com/jaebradley/basketball_reference_web_scraper) may save you some time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the data is hidden in a commented section of the HTML. The table you want to extract is rendered with Javascript in your browser. Requesting the page with requests or urllib just yields the raw HTML.

So be aware that you have to examine the source code of the page with "View page source" rather than the rendered page with "Inspect Element" if you search for the proper tags to find with BeautifulSoup.

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020.html'
html = requests.get(url)

section_start = '<span class="section_anchor" id="team-stats-per_game_link" data-label="Team Per Game Stats">'
block_start = html.text.split(section_start)[1].split("<!--")[1]
block = block_start.split("-->")[0]
soup = BeautifulSoup(block)

data = [th.get_text(",") for th in soup.findAll('tr')]
header = data[0]
header = [x.strip() for x in header.split(",") if x.strip() !=""]
data = [x.split(",") for x in data[1:]]

pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)
```

Explanation: You first need to find the commented section by simply splitting the raw HTML just before the section. You extract the section as text, convert to soup and then parse.

Comment: Thank you!! this helped a lot.